# Android - GData ParseException

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-api-java-client

in our project gdata fails to load youtube playlists **only** if the device language set to Turkish. Here are some logs :

```
 Caused by: com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: Invalid value for attribute : 'name'
    at com.google.gdata.data.AttributeHelper.consumeEnum(AttributeHelper.java:592)
    at com.google.gdata.data.youtube.YtPublicationState.consumeAttributes(YtPublicationState.java:184)
    at com.google.gdata.data.AbstractExtension$AttributesHandler.processEndElement(AbstractExtension.java:263)
    at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.endElement(XmlParser.java:1013)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.ParserAdapter.endElement(ParserAdapter.java:621)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderAdapter.endElement(XMLReaderAdapter.java:353)
    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.endElement(ExpatParser.java:156)
    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.appendChars(Native Method)
    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:497)
    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:484)
    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:309)
    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:267)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderAdapter.parse(XMLReaderAdapter.java:223)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.ParserAdapter.parse(ParserAdapter.java:401)
    at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:694)
    ... 24 more
d[GAThread,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), will retry.
d[Service Reconnect,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), using local store.
 Request failed. Response code: 503, body: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@
```

Looks like the youtube parser fails.This issue is related : https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/issues/detail?id=126, I have download the lastest `gdata` library but nothing helps.Also I have re-build the `gdata` how it described in the `INSTALL-src` file but the new generated `jar`files differ in size(~ > 2kB each) relative to the original `jar`s although I did not change the code. I had such warnings whie build process :

```
[javac] m:\dev\gdata-libs\gdata\java\build-src\core.xml:155: warning: 'inclu
deantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false f
or repeatable builds
      [jar] Building jar: m:\dev\gdata-libs\gdata\java\lib\gdata-youtube-2.0.jar
```

When I try to replace these `jar`s in my project I get verify errors :

```
 Could not find class 'com.google.gdata.data.youtube.VideoFeed', referenced from method com.my.package
10-13 21:14:15.620: W/dalvikvm(32724): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 3981 (Lcom/google/gdata/data/youtube/VideoFeed;) in Lcom/my/package;
```

Appreciate any help.
Thanks, Mike.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to migrate to Data API v3 soonest. [Here's an example Android project with Data API v3.](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android)